# Shorthand for referring to Perl/Moose package names?

Tags: perl, coding-style, package, moose, verbosity

In both Python and Java we have `import` to eliminate the repetition of fully-qualified package/module names throughout code. Is there any equivalent in Perl/Moose? I think it would really make Moose nicer to use if we didn't have to repeat `MyApp::Model::Item`. Instead, I'd like to `[somehow declare] MyApp::Model::Item;` and later on, simply refer to `Item`. I can think of all of these use-cases where class names are used...

- `extends 'Item';`
- `with 'ItemRole';`
- `Item->new(name => 'thing');`
- `method foo(Item $xyz) { ... }`, with `MooseX::Method::Signatures`
- `$var->isa('Item');`
- `try { ... } catch (DatabaseError $e) { ... }`, with `TryCatch`
- `$Item::SOME_PACKAGE_GLOBAL_VARIABLE`

If there is no such thing yet, any idea on how I might start to cleanly implement this? I can see that it would be tricky to deal with cases where the classname is used as a string.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This all works with [`aliased`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?aliased)

```
use aliased 'MyApp::Model::Item';
use aliased 'MyApp::ItemRole';
use aliased 'MyApp::Exception::DatabaseError';

extends Item;
with ItemRole;
Item->new(name => 'thing');
method foo (Item $xyz) { ... }
$var->isa(Item);
try { ... } catch(DatabaseError $e) { ... }
```

This doesn't:

```
$Item::SOME_PACKAGE_GLOBAL_VAR
```

Needing something like that seems to be quite rare, but I suppose it could be made to work with the [`namespace::alias`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?namespace::alias) module.

Comment: and yeah, I rarely need to access a package global, so I can live with spelling out the name in those cases.